# Extract second Line from a text Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, automation, software-design

I need to extract the second line of a text and I have a hard time finding sources where I use JavaScript. My following code is design to get extract the information in the same line.

Text Example:

```
Name: John Smith 

Are you a current customer? 
Yes
```

Code:

```
         if(pmsg.indexOf ("Name: ")>0) {
           var end = pmsg.substring(pmsg.indexOf("Name:")+6,pmsg.length);
           name = end.substring(0, end.indexOf("\n"));
          }
         if(pmsg.indexOf("Are you a current customer? ")>0) {
           var end = pmsg.substring(pmsg.indexOf("Are you a current customer? ")+28,pmsg.length);
```

Desired Output:

```
John Smith
No
```

I have done some research and I think I need to use the ReadLine method? I can extract the name just fine because **"Name: "**  it is in the same line and and I can just say retrieve everything after **Name:** but it is difficult for me to retrieve the next line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I cant figure how you get the email, but you can split the whole string with

`email.split(/\r\n|\n/);`
and save it to an array this would get every line as a different position of the array

hope it works